# how can I send array data from controller to a blade and access the data in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, laravel

I am working with Laravel 6. I have a controller where data is collected after form is submitted, from the data collected I want to use some data to send it to a different page where payment could be collected.

here is my code

```php
//data collected from form for storing in database and sending to payment gateway
public function store()  
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $amount = 1200;
    $orderid = time() . '-' . $user->id;

    auth()->user()->details()->create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'orderID' => $orderid,
        'reptype' => $data['reptype'],
        'gender' => $data['gender'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'phone' => $data['phone'],
    ]);

    $api = new Api(config('app.razorpay'), config('app.razorsecret'));

    $orderData = [
        'receipt'         => $orderid,
        'amount'          => $amount, // 2000 rupees in paise
        'currency'        => 'INR',
        'payment_capture' => 1 // auto capture
    ];

    //create a new order id on payment gateway
    $razorpayOrder = $api->order->create($orderData);

    //collect order ID
    $razorpayOrderId = $razorpayOrder['id'];

    //data to be sent for payment collection
    $pay = [       
        "amount"            => $amount,
        "name"              => "test name",
        "description"       => "",
        "image"             => "https://s29.postimg.org/r6dj1g85z/daft_punk.jpg",
        "prefill"           => [
            "name"              => "Daft Punk",
            "email"             => "customer@merchant.com",
            "contact"           => "9999999999",
        ],
        "notes"             => [
            "address"           => "Hello World",
            "merchant_order_id" => $orderid,   //order id which I have generated
        ],
        "order_id"          => $razorpayOrderId,  //order id provided by gateway
    ];

        return redirect()->route( 'pay')->with($pay);  // I would like to send data from this redirect to a blade where I can initiate payment process.
}
```

My problem is that I want to send `$pay` array data to route `pay` where the `$pay` array data should be accessible to the java script code. when I try doing it I get a message that variable not available.

Comment: You can access in javascript simply by: `var variable= $pay`;

Comment: I have tried that, it says variable undefined

Comment: Try: `return redirect()->route( 'pay', ['pay' => $pay['order_id']]);`

Comment: my only success with having array's accepted by javascript is to do ```var pay = {!! $pay !!}```. You might also need to wrap it within a json_decode. so it would be ```{!! json_decode($pay) !!}``` I'm not at my dev terminal to test but i think this is accurate

Comment: @maximus1127 is this the right way to send data to blade return redirect()->route( 'pay')->with($pay);

Comment: i hardly ever return redirects like you're doing. i always return views and send the data to the view. is that an option for you? or do you have to use a route redirect?

Comment: @maximus1127 not necessarily required to use a route redirect but I thought it would be right thing to be on the correct route when accessing a specific page.. BTW, I have tried both var pay = {!! $pay !!} and {!! json_decode($pay) !!} I get a message undefined variable: pay.

Comment: i would recommend returning the view. it's much cleaner. just change your last line to ```return view('pay', compact('pay'));``` and you should be good to go. just make sure you adjust it to be the actual view. I just thew "pay" in there as an example

Comment: @maximus1127 json_decode($pay) did not work, but I tried json_encode and it did work.. thanks for the help much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can go about this:

## 1. Echoing the variable.

```js
// in your blade file
<script>
let pay = JSON.parse('{{ @json($pay) }}');
</script>
```

The problem with this approach is it can only be used inside a blade file and depends on you instantiating the `pay` before it's used somewhere else.

## 2 Using an attribute, a data-* attribute or a hidden input to store the data and then retrieving it.

```xml
<!-- hidden input value example -->
<input id="pay-data" type="hidden" value='@json($pay)'>
<!-- attribute example -->
<span id="pay-data" type="hidden" someattribute='@json($pay)' style="display:none;"></span>
<!-- data-* attribute example -->
<span id="pay-data" type="hidden" data-payment='@json($pay)' style="display:none;"></span>
```

Using single quotes (') is important. Don't use double quotes (") with the `@json` helper.

```js
// vanilla js - value example
let pay = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('pay-data').value);
// jquery - value example
let pay = JSON.parse($('#pay-data').val());
// vanilla js - attribute example
let pay = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('pay-data').getAttribute('someattribute'));
// jquery - attribute example
let pay = JSON.parse($('#pay-data').attr('someattribute'));
// vanilla js - data-* attribute example
let pay = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('pay-data').dataset.payment);
// jquery - data-* attribute example
let pay = JSON.parse($('#pay-data').data('payment'));
```

There is a downside to doing it like this. The json data is exposed to anyone who wants to examine the html code.

## 3 Getting the data through an ajax call.

Personally, I prefer option 2 or 3 because I don't like mixing my JS with my blade files.

Comment: I am still confused which method is the right one to send data from controller 1.     return view('pay', compact('pay'));   through view or 2.  return redirect()->route( 'pay')->with($pay);

Comment: `view('pay', compact('pay'))` is equivalent to `view('pay', ['pay' => $pay])` or `view('pay')->with('pay', $pay)`. Choose one you like and stick with it.

Comment: I believe I need to first convert array data into JSON before I could follow one of your methods correct?

Comment: No, the `@json` helper takes care of that.

Comment: It's a syntax error. Check which file it's coming from and the line. The error should tell you this.